# problem with logging out from moodle website after closing the browser

Tags: moodle

I have a problem with my moodle website as the users get logged out specially when they close the browser and re-open it.
I set the session timeout to 2 weeks

I tried different session handlers (memcached, redis, file) all with the same problem

even I tried this on moodle.org when I login with my account and close the browser and reopen it I got logged out

is there is a way to make the session to held? a customization on /lip/classes/session/manager.php maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Moodle stores the "currently logged in" status by using a session cookie - one that is automatically cleared by the browser when the browser is closed.

So, it is not related to the session timing out or being closed on the Moodle server, but simply that the identifier that allows Moodle to link that still active session back to the particular browser is no longer present.

Changing this behaviour directly would require changes to the core code to store this session in a permanent cookie, rather than the session cookie currently used.

Alternatively, it should be possible to develop a custom authentication plugin that could create a permanent cookie when a user logs in, then use that to log the user back in again automatically if they returned to the site (with some extra code in place to delete the cookie when the user manually logs out). This wouldn't be too hard to develop (off the top of my head, without working through all the details), but you would need someone with some PHP / Moodle development skills to write it.

Comment: I tried the easiest way to change the core code

I altered the line
    setcookie($cookiename, '', time() - HOURSECS, $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly);
with:
setcookie($cookiename, '', time() + (DAYSECS * 60), $CFG->sessioncookiepath, $CFG->sessioncookiedomain, $cookiesecure, $CFG->cookiehttponly);

at sessionlib.php, but the problem it didn't solve the problem

Comment: If you read the comments in sessionlib.php it makes it very clear that the cookie there is only used to (optionally) store the 'username', so that a user doesn't need to type it in again on next login. This has nothing at all to do with the session cookie, which is defined in lib/classes/session/manager.php - prepare_cookies() function. Look for $sessionoptions - 'lifetime' and set that to something other than 0 (which means 'until browser closed'). However, this is not very secure and I'd suggest you're better implementing an automatic re-login, rather than extending the session.

Comment: I did it, thank you for your help. I'll try to develop some auth plugin to auto login but I'm new in this field, so it will take a while, your solution will do just fine for now. Thanks again.

Comment: I finally created the plugin to re-login users as long as the session not expired.

It will be great if you take a look on it as you are the one who gave me the idea.

https://github.com/fmido88/moodle-auth_relogin

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution that works for you. I had a quick look at the plugin code, but not in any great detail.

Comment: Thanks alot, it works fine now after modifications, because I relied on user_authenticated_hook to save the same sid in the cookie, but the session wasn't started yet when it called, so I used event observer to check the loggedin event and save the cookies instate and it worked.